Nonzero setpoint for LQR with/without steady-state input
Suppose I have a linear dynamical system $x_{t+1} = Ax_t + Bu_t$ that I'm trying to drive to a nonzero target state $x_{ss}$ (suppose that the system is controllable, or that $x_{ss}$ is in the controllable subspace). I have not seen any textbooks dealing with this case explicitly since they just say you can shift the standard zero-setpoint solution through a change of variables (happy to get any books/papers that address this explicitly). By their logic, the cost function is given by:
$$J_{inf,ss} = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (x_t - x_{ss})^TQ(x_t - x_{ss}) + (u_t - u_{ss})^T R (u_t - u_{ss})$$
with the control law given by: $u_t = u_{ss} - K(x_t - x_{ss})$ where $u_{ss} = B^\dagger (I-A) x_{ss}$. Similarly for the finite-horizon case
$$J_{fin,ss} = (x_T - x_{ss})^TF(x_T - x_{ss}) + \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} (x_t - x_{ss})^TQ(x_t - x_{ss}) + (u_t - u_{ss})^T R (u_t - u_{ss})$$
where the control law is $u_t = u_{ss} - K_t(x_t - x_{ss})$. However, this immediately introduces a pitfall that is not addressed by the zero-setpoint case, namely that this might not actually satisfy the equilibrium condition if $(I-A) x_{ss}$ is not in $range(B)$. In the zero-setpoint case, $x_{ss} = Ax_{ss} + Bu_{ss}$ always has an equilibrium $x_{ss} = 0, u_{ss} = 0$.
My question is, what can we do about this? I've considered a few options:

Can we drop the $u_{ss}$ in the cost function like this:

$$J_{inf} = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (x_t - x_{ss})^T Q (x_t - x_{ss}) + u_t^T R u_t$$

Since $x_{ss}$ is not an equilibrium, we can't expect infinite-horizon LQR to hold it there. Can we use finite-horizon LQR instead?

$$J_{fin} = (x_T - x_{ss})^T F (x_T - x_{ss}) + \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} (x_t - x_{ss})^T Q (x_t - x_{ss}) + u_t^T R u_t$$
2a) We can let $Q=0$ and $F\neq0$, supposing we only want to reach $x_{ss}$ at time $T$. I think this can be solved with a time-varying feedforward term $u_t = K_t (x_t - x_{ss}) + v_t$, is this correct?
2b) Or $Q\neq0$, supposing we want to get there by time $T$ but also be reasonably close to $x_{ss}$ throughout the trajectory.
For each of these cases, I'm trying to understand:

Does it even have a closed-form LQR solution?
What would be the behavior?
Is there and equivalence between these four cases from the perspective of the control law, or perhaps is one a special/limiting case of another?
In the case where $(x_{ss}, u_{ss})$ is an equilibrium, are there any equivalences?

Finally, I am new to control theory, so please let me know if this question even makes sense to ask, or what is a better way to think about this.
